# read tiff file directly to numpy array without saving to disk

Tags: python, image, numpy, python-xarray, rasterio

I often download (geo) tiff files, save them to a temporary disk space, then read in the data using [rasterio](https://github.com/mapbox/rasterio) to get a `numpy.ndarray` that I can then analyze.

For example, using [this url for NAIP imagery](https://gis.apfo.usda.gov/arcgis/rest/services/NAIP/Montana_2015_1m/ImageServer/exportImage?f=image&bbox=-12254049.546523554,5821468.735961318,-12201729.385850716,5874434.671211511&imageSR=102100&bboxSR=102100&format=tiff&pixelType=U8&size=512,512&interpolation=%20RSP_BilinearInterpolation):

```
import os
from requests import get
from rasterio import open as rasopen

req = get(url, verify=False, stream=True)
if req.status_code != 200:
    raise ValueError('Bad response from NAIP API request.')
temp = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'temp', 'tile.tif')
with open(temp, 'wb') as f:
    f.write(req.content)
with rasopen(temp, 'r') as src:
    array = src.read()
    profile = src.profile
os.remove(temp)
```

For other (netcdf) geographic gridded data, I might use [xarray](https://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/) to get data
from [this url to get Gridmet data](http://thredds.northwestknowledge.net:8080/thredds/ncss/MET/pet/pet_2011.nc?var=potential_evapotranspiration&north=49.1&west=-116.4&east=-103.0&south=44.3&&horizStride=1&time_start=2011-01-01T00%3A00%3A00Z&time_end=2011-12-31T00%3A00%3A00Z&timeStride=1&accept=netcdf4):

```
from xarray import open_dataset

xray = open_dataset(url)
variable = 'pr' # precipitation
subset = xray.loc[dict(lat=slice(north, south),
                       lon=slice(west,east))]
arr = subset.variable.values
```

So getting an xarray object works as a stream and is easy to get into an `ndarray`, but I only know of this working on netcdf datasets.  Is there a way to 'stream' in tif data to an `ndarray` object?  Ideally, one could do this with

```
with rasopen(url, 'r') as src:
    array = src.read()
```

as `rasterio` returns a nice metadata object along with the `ndarray`, though I have not gotten that to work with a url resource.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can either read it from memory:

```
from rasterio.io import MemoryFile

with MemoryFile(data) as memfile:
    with memfile.open() as dataset:
        data_array = dataset.read()
```

Or directly from a URL:

```
with rasterio.open('https://pathto.tif') as dataset:
    print(dataset.profile)
```

I couldn't get the latter to work with your URL though so you may want to try the first.